# Javascript get custom object based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, object, drop-down-menu

ok. i have several custom objects. These objects are filled with arrays.
I have a drop down with choices. I want to be able to get an object by its name, using a variable based on the dropdown choice.

as for the object, as the title says, i am speaking about a new object created by myself. I have searched high and low unsuccessfully, so far as i can tell, to get the variable to locate this object. sample code is as follows.

```
myobject1 = {
property1 : ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'],
property2 : ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'],
property3 : ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3']
}
myobject2 = {
property1 : ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'],
property2 : ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'],
property3 : ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3']
}

function getmyobject(){
var1 = mydd.value; //contains 'myobject1'
//code to strip and filter out non-alphanumerics and spaces, also to lcase
var2 = window.var1;
for (conditions to loop){
    //code to make the loop spit out i for each array inside of object
}
```

it returns an undefined unless i replace window.var1 with window.objname where objname is the actual name of the object, thus defeating the dynamicism of the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window[var1]` (I guess var1 is a string).

Comment: that was it. the one thing i didn't try because i tried so many things like it. ty. can't wait for this project to get done with.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
eval("var2 = window." + var1);
```